# Extracting sublists with a specific signature from a multi-level list

Tags: list-manipulation

The title is perhaps not clearly written as to my intent - so here is an example.

I have the following list:

```
{{{},{8,8}},{18,192},{{},{7,8}},{17,192},{{},{6,16}},{16,32},{{},{5,16}},{15,32},{{},{4,2}},{14,8},{{},{3,2}},{13,8},{{{{},{2,1}},{10,8}},{12,64}},{20,64},{{{{},{1,1}},{9,8}},{11,64}},{19,64}}
```

What I want is to form a nested list that just has the non-empty sublists of two elements.

i.e. from the example list I want to return

```
{{8, 8}, {18, 192}, {7, 8}, {17, 192}, {6, 16}, {16, 32}, {5, 
  16}, {15, 32}, {4, 2}, {14, 8}, {3, 2}, {13, 8}, {2, 1}, {10, 
  8}, {12, 64}, {20, 64}, {1, 1}, {9, 8}, {11, 64}, {19, 64}}
```

I have tried various combinations of Flatten and/or Join but I cannot seem to get what I would like. Something tells me this is probably not that difficult (though it obviously is for myself) - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: True - but it doesn't help with the variable levels I am left with. You must have edited your comment because you mentioned Catenate - which doesn't help here.

Comment: `Cases[lst, List[_Integer, _Integer], Infinity]` should do it.

Comment: @Alan - yep that works. Thanks.

Comment: This is a very good question and I proposed an edit of title on how to find empty sublist on multi levels or something of that sort. Now I see someone has changed it to extracting sublist with special signature?!? Would anyone new to MMA who want to learn this would search "Extracting sublists with a specific SIGNATURE" ?!!!

Comment: @MathX - Yeah I just noticed the edit someone did - I agree with you the title might be a tad obscure now.

Comment: I liked your title better. I tried to help make it a little easier to find in search but yours was fine to be honest.

Comment: You mention using  `Flatten`:   `Flatten[data][[# ;; # + 1]] & /@ Range[1, Length[Flatten[data]], 2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to the approach taken by Syed, but in one pass:

```
yourList = {{{}, {8, 8}}, {18, 192}, {{}, {7, 8}}, {17, 
    192}, {{}, {6, 16}}, {16, 32}, {{}, {5, 16}}, {15, 
    32}, {{}, {4, 2}}, {14, 8}, {{}, {3, 2}}, {13, 
    8}, {{{{}, {2, 1}}, {10, 8}}, {12, 64}}, {20, 
    64}, {{{{}, {1, 1}}, {9, 8}}, {11, 64}}, {19, 64}};

Cases[yourList, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, All]

(* Out:
{ {8, 8}, {18, 192}, {7, 8}, {17, 192}, {6, 16}, {16, 32}, 
  {5, 16}, {15, 32}, {4, 2}, {14, 8}, {3, 2}, {13, 8}, {2, 1},
  {10, 8}, {12, 64}, {20, 64}, {1, 1}, {9, 8}, {11, 64}, {19, 64}}
*)
```

Comment: I like that - I'll accept this as an "official" answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Empty List may be removed "by .. /. {}->Nothing" and nested lists by: "{x1_List, x2_List} :> Sequence[x1, x2]":

```
d = {{{}, {8, 8}}, {18, 192}, {{}, {7, 8}}, {17, 
    192}, {{}, {6, 16}}, {16, 32}, {{}, {5, 16}}, {15, 
    32}, {{}, {4, 2}}, {14, 8}, {{}, {3, 2}}, {13, 
    8}, {{{{}, {2, 1}}, {10, 8}}, {12, 64}}, {20, 
    64}, {{{{}, {1, 1}}, {9, 8}}, {11, 64}}, {19, 64}};
d //. {{} -> Nothing, {x1_List, x2_List} :> Sequence[x1, x2]}

(*{{8, 8}, {18, 192}, {7, 8}, {17, 192}, {6, 16}, {16, 32}, {5, 
  16}, {15, 32}, {4, 2}, {14, 8}, {3, 2}, {13, 8}, {2, 1}, {10, 
  8}, {12, 64}, {20, 64}, {1, 1}, {9, 8}, {11, 64}, {19, 64}} *)
```

Comment: Yes, that works nicely. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 5):

```
alist = {{{}, {8, 8}}, {18, 192}, {{}, {7, 8}}, {17, 
   192}, {{}, {6, 16}}, {16, 32}, {{}, {5, 16}}, {15, 
   32}, {{}, {4, 2}}, {14, 8}, {{}, {3, 2}}, {13, 
   8}, {{{{}, {2, 1}}, {10, 8}}, {12, 64}}, {20, 
   64}, {{{{}, {1, 1}}, {9, 8}}, {11, 64}}, {19, 64}}
```

If you have to include complex and reals as well use the following variation (otherwise change to `_Integer`):

```
pos = Position[alist, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2}, {3, 2}, {4}, {5, 2}, {6}, {7, 2}, {8}, {9, 
>   2}, {10}, {11, 2}, {12}, {13, 1, 1, 2}, {13, 1, 2}, {13, 
>   2}, {14}, {15, 1, 1, 2}, {15, 1, 2}, {15, 2}, {16}}
> ```

```
Extract[alist, pos]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

Notice the positions:

```
yourlist // Flatten // Partition[#,2]&
```